# Set name of a input box from a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code

```
$("#inputs").append("&lt;input class=\"adding\" id=\"test"+ values + "\ name=\"" + values + ">"+ values + "&lt;/input>&lt;br />");
```

I have a variable named `values`.
This code is put in the click method of it this appends the input box correctly but when I use AJAX to send the values and echo, it works fine only for the 1st value which I haven't used the jQuery `append()` function but instead just used HTML. What's my problem here?

Comment: HTML code would be very helpful and more jquery

Comment: Is that an input box? I don't see a type in it

Comment: Are the Names for these inputs the same

Comment: What is the relevant AJAX code?

Comment: also the ajax function would be helpful. MORE CODE

Comment: Where you go: id=\"test"+ values + "\ name= the last backslash needs a " after it i assume?

Comment: Well the everything is fine except that i dont know where to put the backslashes.

Comment: @Kristoffer pls put a complete answer(code) as it would be difficult to understand this. Thanks

Comment: `input` is self-closing, so you should just use `<input />` instead of `<input></input>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is generic without the relevant code snippets to your ajax, HTML and server code.

The only thing I can do is fix up your input creation code so that it's readable and maintainable.

```
$("#inputs")
.append(
    $("<input />", {
        "class": "adding",
        "id": "test" + values,
        "name": values,
        "val": values
    }))
.append($("<br/>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple rewrite with back slash:

```
$("#inputs").append("&lt;input class=\"adding\" id=\"test" + values + "\" name=\"" + values + "\">"+ values + "&lt;/input>&lt;br />");
```